# Set expected version (optimistic locking)

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, optimistic-locking

My application is using Spring Data JPA (Hibernate). The application exposes a REST API which allows to manipulate the data in the persistence store (using Hibernate).

If a REST client (of the application) wants to update something he would send in the expected version number of the entity along with the data. There's an RFC for that, but it is besides the point here. Bottom line: I get some "expected version" value along with the `PUT` or `PATCH` operation.

My entity looks like this:

```java
@Entity
public class Person {

  @Version
  @Column(name="entity_version")
  private Long version;

   // getters and setters
}
```

On an incoming `PUT` or `PATCH` operation, I do this:

1. Retrieve existing entity from the database.
2. Set the "expected version" using `person.setVersion(expectedVersionReceivedFromRestClient)`.
3. Apply the new/updated data to the entity.
4. Then perform `repo.save(entity)`.

Now, if the REST client sends some very weird long number as the expected version, I would assume that I would get an `OptimisticLockException`. However, this doesn't happen.

I've debugged and it seems Hibernate will refresh the entity just prior to merging it. Thus the value I set with the `setVersion()` is lost and the merge operation thereby always succeeds. Not what I expected!

I've read various docs that say that I shouldn't manually call set value on any `@Version` annotated property. But how then can I marry the stateless REST world with that of the JPA model?

I think I have [THIS PROBLEM](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/26365), but I have to admit, I do not understand any of it.  :-(

### Analysis of Spring Data REST

Based on the comments it seems clear that we cannot manually set `@Version` annotated property value.

It would be obvious to look into how Spring Data REST solves this problem (although I do not use it in my project) as it is able to expose a JPA repository using REST and it supports conditional operations using the `If-Match` http header.

So what *actually* happens when you do say a PUT request with an `If-Match` header which doesn't match the current version value of the database?

As far as I can tell it [checks the version first](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/blob/667a49b3ab4dd94c2e00d31333fb564f4a93815f/spring-data-rest-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/support/ETag.java#L100) and then moves on to perform the actual update of the entity in the database. This is not safe, IMHO. It is quite easy for two operations to happen at approx the same time and both will pass the check and then they will both move on to update the entity. Thus, the lost update syndrome is *not* solved.
(The Spring Data REST documentation doesn't mention this deficiency, so please comment if you think I'm wrong)

### The bullet proof solution?

All in all, the only mechanism that would be "safe" in a concurrent world would be if the solution generated SQL as follows:

```sql
UPDATE persons
SET    ..., -- set column values
      entity_version = entity_version+1       
WHERE id = :id
AND   entity_version = :expected_entity_version
```

If the above updated exactly 1 row it means the update happened as expected. If the above updated 0 rows it means we should raise `412 Precondition Failed`. (incidentally this is how Hibernate deals with @Version, but as we've already established, unfortunately we cannot leverage JPA/Hibernate's @Version feature here)

### Restating the problem

The question is: How to build a safe "conditional-update" REST API on top of a Spring Data JPA solution?   By "safe", I mean that concurrent updates do not override each other. Above, I've looked into how Spring Data REST solves this problem and I've argued that I don't think it solves it all.

There has to someone out there who has tried this?  :-)

Answer (score 0):

The version is managed by Hibernate and is needed to prevent updating entities in parallel transactions. What happens between GET and PUT requests - is not a DB transaction, so you shouldn't solve it in such way. [Hibernate doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#locking-optimistic-version-number) says: *Your application is forbidden from altering the version number set by Hibernate*.

If you want, you can manually check that the version from a request is equal to the version of the existing entity. But in my opinion, `@CreatedDate` is more suitable for that case because is human-readable.

Comment: Well, anything I invent on my own will not be fully safe (considering multiple concurrent REST requests). By contrast, the JPA Optimistic Locking feature guarantees me this. Hence, I want to leverage that.
I need a way to tell Hibernate: Please update this entity, but only if entity is currently at version-level X, otherwise fail the request.

Comment: My plan will work correctly in multiple concurrent REST requests. I don't offer you to remove the version, so optimistic lock will check that the entity is not updated in parallel transactions. But if you want to check that an entity was not modified in consecutive transactions, Hibernate can't help you, you need to add such verification manually.

Comment: You would need a solution that does it all in _one atomic action_. For example, at the SQL level:   `UPDATE persons SET .. WHERE entity_version=:x`.  ... rather than do the check in step 1 and the update in step 2, which I think is what you suggest? In the SQL example a return value of 0 (no rows updated) should then raise an exception. Something like that.

Comment: You are right that my solution needs two requests. But my main point is that what you want is your own business logic, it's not about transactions and tasks that Hibernate helps solve.

Comment: I wouldn't think I'm the first person in the world attempting to put a REST-CRUD API on top of some JPA ?  I'm thinking there has to be a generally-agreed upon solution for how to deal with this?

Comment: The generally agreed solution is to find an entity, verify it, and then save it. You need two requests anyway because you have to fetch an entity from DB before if you want to set new values from the front to it.